# How to install user feedback polls for github issues?

Tags: github, configuration, polling, user-feedback

I want to automatically create polls in GitHub issues.  I visited https://github.com/evenchange4/gh-polls-bot and added that to my GH repository and now `Polls` appears on my `Installed GitHub Apps` settings page.  Yet when I create an issue that includes the example text `/polls Option1 'Option 2' "Option 3"` on a blank line all by itself, no poll appears.

What else is needed to enable the polling to show up?

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/evenchange4/gh-polls-bot/issues/26#issuecomment-701514560